# html 5 offline storage

Tags: html, local-storage, offline

Hi I have a question about html5 offline storage..When I have a site which is dynamicaly generated in php and I want make it accessible offline...I have a manifest file with all images, js, css and so on, but should I include too URLs of proper sites? Or when I go on particular part of my site, it will automatically save html markup and when reloading it will choose the cached version?
I have main template where I have linked the manifest file with all the cached stuff (for whole site), so every generated html document have the same manifest file linked in..
How is that working?

Comment: Just wondering you don't mean to make something like this right? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Sync_Framework

Answer (score 1):

There are two different approaches you can take with including files in your cache manifest.

1. If you want everything to be available immediately, you need to list all the urls in the cache manifest.  All of those url's will be cached when the first page loads.
2. If you want to lazy load pages into the cache, you only need to include the images, js, css, and other supplementary files.  When you go to the first page with a cache manifest specified, it will cache that page and all the files listed in the manifest.  Other html pages will not be cached until you actually visit them.  If you went offline immediately, you would only have a single html file in the manifest.

For our site, we chose option 1, because we wanted all pages related to the current day's content to be available immediately.

Comment: ok thanks..and do you know something about memory restrictions in offline storage?what is the max capacity of my cache (on iOS os it 10MB on newer devices, so pretty low amount of possibly stored data), I need to store lot of images, but chrome says, It would exceed data quota or something like this..

Comment: It varies between browsers.  Most give you about 5MB.  Some of them let the user increase the available size.